# Unable to mount remote folder with sshfs

Tags: ubuntu, remote-access, sshfs

Both are ubuntu machines. I checked the IP of my other machine which is pingable as well. But When I do `sudo sshfs r@192.168.1.4:/home/r/ /home/r/link/`, it does not work. I get the message `Connection reset by peer`. Any ideas what might be wrong here ? 
What can I do to detect the problem ?

Comment: If you use `sshfs -d r@192.168.1.4:/home/r/ /home/r/link/` it will display some debug information. Can you get the data and edit the question?

Comment: Actually I didn't have an ssh server running.  Fixed it by installing open-ssh. Thanks for the hint though.

Comment: Check your permissions, or `r` user `UID==0`.